# R: How to use margins of a 3-dimensional array as individual arguments to the same function?

Tags: r, arrays, function

I have an array named TOM. The command `dim(TOM)` returns *2, 4000, 4000*.

When I run:

```
consensusTOM <- pmin(TOM[1, , ], TOM[2, , ])
```

It returns a matrix containing the parallel minima values between the two input arguments, which is exactly what I need.

I want to write a function that, for whatever value I have for the first margin of this array, would apply `pmin()` considering each element as an individual argument to the `pmin()` function.

Then, if I input an array of dimensions *3, 4000, 4000*, it would do:

```
consensusTOM <- pmin(TOM[1, , ], TOM[2, , ], TOM[3, , ])
```

Likewise, if I input an array of dimensions *4, 4000, 4000*, it would do:

```
consensusTOM <- pmin(TOM[1, , ], TOM[2, , ], TOM[3, , ], TOM[4, , ])
```

And so on and so forth.

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to change it to a `list` by looping over the first dimension and then use `pmin` within `do.call`

```
do.call(pmin, lapply(seq(dim(TOM)[1]), function(i) TOM[i,,]))
```